# Why is RowPrePaint on top of everything and how do i change that?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

As I've been building my app I have come across several problems due to the use of `RowPrePaint`. The event seems to be pasted on top of everything, no matter the order in which the code executes.

I had a problem where cell ToolTip would lie underneath it; I had to just find a completely different method to convey the text of the cell. 
Now I'm simply trying to show a messagebox if my If Statement isn't met, but even that won't show unless the user presses the Alt key (I've checked by turning it off and running the code again).

So my question is why does the `RowPrePaint` event put itself above everything and is there a way i can change that without moving my code to the `cellformatting` event? Thanks in advance.

I've included my if statement below but i know it's not the code itself that's the issue.

```
    Dim RSScon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Comment FROM StepBackTable WHERE Retsch_ID = '" & Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(0).Value) & "' AND Col_index = '" & Convert.ToInt32(columnindex) & "';", RSScon)

    Dim Rdr_Info As SqlDataReader

    RSScon.Open()
    Rdr_Info = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default)

    If Rdr_Info.HasRows Then   
        While Rdr_Info.Read()
            ViewComForm.Show()
            ViewComForm.TextBox1.Text = Rdr_Info("Comment")
        End While
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("There are no comments assiated with this stage of the job",
                "Important Note", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End If

    Rdr_Info.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    RSScon.Close()
```

**EDIT : RowPrePaint Code for TaW**

```
        For colval1 As Integer = 5 To 28
        If Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value) = 1 Or Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value) = 5 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval1).Value = 2
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value = 1
        ElseIf Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value) = 4 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval1).Value = 4
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value = 4
        End If

    Next colval1

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 7 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If

    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value)

    Select Case value
        Case "0"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Case "1"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Case "2"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
        Case "4"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Case "5"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
    End Select

    For colval As Integer = 6 To 28
        Dim value6 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Value

        Select Case value6
            Case "0"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            Case "1"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Case "2"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Case "3"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Case "4"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Case "5"
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
        End Select

    Next colval

    Dim value29 As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value
    Select Case value29
        Case "0"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Case "1"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
        Case "4"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    End Select

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value = 5 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = 5
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).Value = 5
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(10).Value = 5 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(11).Value = 5
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(12).Value = 5
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(13).Value = 5 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(14).Value = 5
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(15).Value = 5
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(16).Value = 5
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(22).Value = 5 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(23).Value = 5
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(27).Value = 5 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(29).Value = 1
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(9).Value = 1 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 7 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(10).Value = 1
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(12).Value = 1 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 7 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(13).Value = 1
    End If

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(19).Value = 1 And DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value = 7 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(20).Value = 1
    End If
```

Comment: It is a Paint event and draw onto the Control's surface. I don't think you can change that. What exactly is it you want above it? I see no relevance in the code you posted..

Comment: What does the code you posted have to do with `RowPrePaint`?

Comment: @TaW When the Event is on it won't let me post the message box under `else`, it puts it behind my form, then to bring it to the front you have to press the alt key. Surely the message box should always be on top?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar because when the `RowPrePaint` event is included it won't show the messagebox under `Else` in that piece of code. It send it behind the form for some unknown reason

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce and also can't imagine how that hapens at your place. You may need to __show__ the `RowPrePaint` code!

Comment: @TaW I will post the code but warning there's a lot

Comment: If think you're using this wrong. You should not set any cell values in `RowPrePaint`. You should stick to either just setting values (colors, brushes, etc.) in the `Graphics` object of the event parameter or you can start painting stuff. But it is the wrong place for setting cell values/call properties. Especially since setting values/cell properties can again trigger a new `RowPrePaint` event.

Comment: Crystal ball says that this code runs on a worker thread.  Pretty common for slow dbase queries.  Bad idea in more than one way, *never* display UI on a worker thread.  And yes, the message box window has no Z-order relationship with the rest of your windows, it has the desktop window as the owner.  So can easily pop up behind another window.  Do this correctly, only gather the data in a worker.  Keep the UI updates on the UI thread.  Easily done with the BackgroundWorker class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I moved the bottom part of the code to `CellClick` event and it does change the cell value more efficiently, but unfortunately that didn't solve the messagebox problem.

Comment: As has been noted, the Paint events are mean just for Drawing; even the CellStyles should be set in the cellformatting event. None of the code draws anything. Also: you are setting Values not just at the bottom but also at the top of the code.. -

Comment: @TaW the reason I'm using the `PreRowPaint` instead is because it's quicker when the app is run. moving the code to `CellFormatting` still produces the same result. I'm going to have a look at background worker like @Hans has suggested, this looks like a promising method

Comment: The perceived speed difference porobably comes from the number of calls: CellFormatting once for each Cell, rowPaint once for each Row. But the real issue is indeed not to do any outside stuff in there!