# Faulty DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, vb.net, datetimepicker

I've got a small form on my app where the user can select a date, press submit and the date will get placed in DataGridView cell.

When a user tries to select a date in the past the DateTimePicker will kind of lag a month behind, then if you try to go forward to match up the date the month will then be one ahead, making it difficult to select the correct date.

I really have no idea why the DTP is doing this, as I have many others in my app and they all work fine. I've tried expanding the form in case it's because the tools are overlapping but that doesn't help.

I've inserted a step by step set of pictures of myself attempting to select the 4th of February to show what happens along with the form code. Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
 Private Sub CloseButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub intBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles intBTN.Click
    Dim rowindex As Integer = Form4.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex()
    Dim colindex As Integer = Form4.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex()

    Form4.DataGridView1.Rows(rowindex).Cells(colindex + 1).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value      
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub EnterDateForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the code shown we can't really help, as it does not affect the DTP at all. Is this everything? Have you got any DTP event handled?

Comment: Yeah I added the code just in case anyone was interested but I don't believe it's a coding problem. There isn't any other code related to the DTP except in that block. Any other code in the app relates to the date that this form puts in the Datagridview. Do you know of any default properties that might be screwing with the DTP?

Comment: Did you check existing code to verify there is no events that are changing the dates?

Comment: I've never seen something like this, so I don't think there is any default property but maybe something you have changed. What about removing the dtp and adding a new one?

Comment: @jdweng Yeah I've checked all forms just in case and there's nothing I can see that would effect this DTP.

Comment: @Pikoh yes I've tried removing it and adding a new one and putting multiple ones on the same form with completely different names and they all have the same issue. It is very strange

Comment: Actually I think I know what it is. I've used RowPrePaint on the form behind and I have had several issues with using tools and objects from VS while this form is active. For example a message box would never show up in front of the form, or I couldn't put tool tips on my DGV. I always had to find work arounds for this issue and couldn't fully solve or understand it.

Comment: Is there any code in the designer cs files that may cause issue?

Comment: I've checked and I can't see anything that would. But after further study it definitely is the RowPrePaint event causing the issue. I posted a previous question on SO about it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863268/why-is-rowprepaint-on-top-of-everything-and-how-do-i-change-that I didn't understand or get to grips with how a background worker is used or could be utilised in my situation so I just found work arounds..