# How to put my subs in a backgroundworker

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

On my app I've got 2 subs that seem to be blocking the UI, RowPrePaint and CellFormatting. These 2 subs paint my DataGridView cells certain colours based on what value is inside the cell.

Based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863268/why-is-rowprepaint-on-top-of-everything-and-how-do-i-change-that) I asked I came to the conclusion that I needed another thread. (Hans Passant recommended a BackgroundWorker) I was still a novice back then so I just found work arounds for my problems, and now they've caught up to me because tools like DateTimePicker won't function correctly on my UI.

I've been looking for examples and all of them seem to include the backgroundworker involving a progress bar or similar. Also I've come accross a rule that says never access UI objects on a thread that didn't create them. So i'm confused if these subs should even be put on a backgroundworker?

So does anyone know any examples similar to this that I could learn off? Or has any advice to how I can put these subs on different threads? Thanks in advance. I've included the 2 troublemaaker subs

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint

    Dim Row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)   

    If Row.Cells(3).Value = 7 Then
        Row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Row.Cells(3).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
    ElseIf Row.Cells(3).Value = 8 Then
        Row.Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Row.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Row.Cells(2).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Row.Cells(3).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Row.Cells(4).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If

    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Row.Cells(5).Value)

    Select Case value
        Case "0"
            Row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
            Row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Case "1"
            Row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
        Case "2"
            Row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
        Case "4"
            Row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
        Case "5"
            Row.Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Row.Cells(1).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Row.Cells(2).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Row.Cells(4).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Row.Cells(5).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Row.Cells(5).Style.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
    End Select

    For colval As Integer = 7 To 51 Step 2

        Dim value6 As Integer = Row.Cells(colval).Value

        Select Case value6
            Case "0"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            Case "1"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.LightSkyBlue
            Case "2"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Case "3"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Orange
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Orange
            Case "4"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Case "5"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.RoyalBlue
            Case "6"
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                Row.Cells(colval).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End Select

    Next colval

    Dim value53 As Integer = Row.Cells(53).Value

    Select Case value53
        Case "0"
            Row.Cells(53).Style.BackColor = Color.Empty
            Row.Cells(53).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
        Case "1"
            Row.Cells(53).Style.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse
            Row.Cells(53).Style.ForeColor = Color.Chartreuse
        Case "4"
            Row.Cells(53).Style.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
            Row.Cells(53).Style.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
    End Select

End Sub
```

---

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    For k = 8 To 52 Step 2
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)                                                 'Declare part of the code to equal row (runs the code faster)
        If row.Cells(k).Value Is DBNull.Value Or row.Cells(k).Value Is Nothing Then Continue For                    'If the database has a null cell or the cell is nothing continue

        Dim firstDate As Date = DirectCast(row.Cells(k).Value, Date)                                                'Declare firstdate as a cell value and convert to date type
        Dim N As Date = Now                                                                                         'Declare N as the date today
        Dim diff As TimeSpan = N - firstDate                                                                        'Declare diff as the tome between N and firstdate

        If diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(k + 1).Value = 0 Then                                                   'If the difference between 'diff' is over 14 and col in front of k equals 0
            row.Cells(k - 1).Value = 6                                                                              'Make col behind k = 6
        ElseIf diff.Days > 14 AndAlso row.Cells(k + 1).Value <> 0 Then                                              'Or if the difference between 'diff' is over 14 and col in front of k does not equal 0
            row.Cells(k - 1).Value = row.Cells(k - 3).Value                                                         'Make col behind k equal the value of the col 3 rows behind k
        End If
    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: These event subs are called automatically by the datagridview so  putting them into a background worker is impossible. You can however move the code inside the worker but you cant access datagridview directly. Instead you have to invoke the grid to read its properties. 

The `CellFormatting` runs on every new cell being displayed. DO NOT LOOP in it. use `e.ColumnIndex` instead of `k`. Even so doing value manipulation in the formatting event isn't really the way to go either.

Comment: In both of your methods it makes no sense to execute them in the background. These are mostly UI operations and there is no lengthy external operation involved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @keith I asked this question because these 2 specific subs are causing interference with the UI and blocking message boxes from appearing oin front etc. From your comment would you say these blocks of code should be in different subs?

Comment: @Sefe thats why Hans comment on my other question threw me a bit. These 2 code block are blocking the UI though and I'm struggling to work out why..

Comment: The subs themselves are not the problem - the code in them is wrong.  Also, turn on Option Strict - an integer can never, ever be "3" or "5"

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the reply. I do already have option strict on and no errors are popping up. so if i correct the code by taking the loop out of cell formatting etc. then it should work?

Comment: Sorry, but `Select Case value ... Case "0"` when value is an integer will not compile under `Option Strict` - you are comparing an integer to a string literal. [This is applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39732962) in several regards

Comment: Hi @KeithMifsud I want to replace the loops in my subs as I think that will solve my problem, but I need the code block to affect every 2nd column in the `DataGridView`. How could I change `k` to `e.ColumnIndex` and still only have it work on every 2 columns?

Comment: you can use the `Mod` operator. `If e.ColumnIndex >= 8 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex <= 52 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then` This will eliminate the for loop and replace all `k` with `e.ColumnIndex`